# Load PDF in ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift3, uicontainerview

Problem: 1. How do I display a PDF in a containerview?
         2. Can I make it scale to fit (ie. if there are only a few lines in the pdf can I make the pdf viewer only be a few lines in size?

Context: I am building a free SAT Math practice app, to build the multiple choice section I need to load a pdf version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use uidocumentinteractioncontroller to load pdf it can be b used in container view 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130